# Does each shared reference take up another word of memory (e.g. 32 or 64 bits) in Java?

Tags: java, memory, reference

Let's say 3 objects each have a reference to an object `x`, do each of those 3 references take up another word of memory (e.g. 32 or 64 bits, meaning a grand total of 96 or 192 bits), even if they have all been set to the very same object?

e.g.

```
X x = getX();
object1.x = x;
object2.x = x;
object3.x = x;
```

?

Furthermore, if I have a `HashMap<Character, Character>`, where I always enter the exact same `Character` object as both key and value, does it take up double the memory of the references in a `HashSet<Character>` plus the amount of memory for the `Characters` themselves, even though the same object reference is being used for both key and value each time? I know this might be the same as the first question but I wonder if this case might behave any differently?

In each of these cases, if the root objects are `static`, are the references stored on the stack or the heap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference always takes up the same amount of memory, typically 32-bit even on 64-bit JVMs.  It doesn't get smaller just because it references the same object as another reference.

> does it take up double the memory of the references

No. HashSet is a wrapper for HashMap so it consumes the same amount of memory.

> In each of these cases, if the root objects are static, are the references stored on the stack or the heap?

static fields are always stored on the heap in HotSpot but AFAIK it not specified in the JLS so it could be different.  It wouldn't make sense to place it on the stack as that is thread local.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you have multiple references, each reference occupies separate memory regardless of where it points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have 3 references, so it's 3 times the memory for the reference.

The `Character` object takes the memory for the reference plus its content (say, a `char`). A `char` primitive would only consume the space for the primitive (which is less then just a reference on a 64bit system). If you are using the *same* object as key and value, then you look at two references and 1 object.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you write, no additional memory is being consumed that wasn't already being consumed.  You're just changing the contents of the references `object1.x`, `object2.x`, and `object3.x`.

In the current JDK, a `HashMap<Character, Character>` will take up the same amount of memory as a `HashSet<Character>` of the same size.  (Slightly *less*, actually.)  This is independent of whether or not it maps characters to themselves.

Only method-local reference variables are stored on the stack; everything else is stored on the heap.  In particular, a field of any object (regardless of whether it is `static` or not) will be stored, like the rest of the object, on the heap.

Comment: For Java 6, string literals are stored in the perm gen. ;) In Java 7 they are on the heap.

Comment: The above simplification probably suffices for the OP without getting into more confusing topics.

Comment: Like where is the information for stack traces stored before they are turned into an StackTraceElement[] ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Share links :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of an object like a row in a database table: it doesn't matter if two rows have the same value for a given column: still the value has to be saved in the specific row, so yes if two users share the name *John*, your table grows to host two John's :)

```
+------------------------------+
|   ID   |        NAME         |
+--------+---------------------+
|0x76BA39|       John          |
+--------+---------------------+
|0xB4H821|       John          |
+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects x, object1, object2 and object3 will be allocated on the heap once. Each of the last three objects will reference instance x via a reference. No additional memory will be required for each of those objects, besides the reference property (assuming they don't have any other property). Generally the space consumed for each object depends on its properties. Each allocated object requires in addition by the jvm a header, typically including a mark word, class metadata and if the instance is an array its length (see http://www.cs.princeton.edu/picasso/mats/HotspotOverview.pdf).

Statically defined class properties are allocated in the class definition located in the permanent generation (in hotspot) during the class initialization phase (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5).